Why does the first function work but the second one doesn't?
A string literal supposed to be deduced as a const char array, then it decays to a const char* pointer. This is why this works:
struct MyStringView
{
    template <int N>
    MyStringView(const char(&arr)[N]) : str(&arr[0]), size(N - 1){ 
        
    }
    const char* str;
    int size;
};


MyStringView getName(int number)
{
    switch (number)
    {
    case 1: return "One";
    case 2: return "Two";
    case 3: return "Three";

    }
}

int main()
{

    auto string_view = getName(1);
}

Even though MyStringView doesn't have a constructor taking a const char*.
But this doesn't work:
template <bool bAsInteger>
MyStringView getName2(int number)
{
    switch (number)
    {
        // RETURN CANNOT CONVERT FROM CONST CHAR* TO MyStringView
        // HOWEVER return bAsInteger ? MyStringView("1") : MyStringView("One") works
    case 1: return bAsInteger ? "1" : "One";
    case 2: return bAsInteger ? "2" : "Two";
    case 3: return bAsInteger ? "3" : "Three";

    }
}


int main()
{
    string_view = getName2<true>(1);
}

Why doesn't this work? Why's it now looking for a const char* constructor?

Amusingly the following does work:
case 1: return bAsInteger ? "111" : "One";
case 2: return bAsInteger ? "222" : "Two";
case 3: return bAsInteger ? "33333" : "Three";


Because the return type of conditional operator will be a common type deduced from its operands.
For bAsInteger ? "1" : "One", the operands are "1" (const char[2]) and "One" (const char[4]), then the common type is deduced as const char *. So bAsInteger ? "1" : "One" always returns const char*, which is used to construct MyStringView later.
